# Is it possible to clear a .CDX file?

Tags: database, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I was ordered to clean out some .dbf files (foxpro databases).
After "zap" them with a program I downloaded I found that the .cdx files associated to them had partial information about the rows deleted in the dbf files.

Is there any way of clearing the dbf/cdx  files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

from within VFP, you can use the table exclusively and delete all index tags, thus removing the reference to the .CDX files... Ex:

Use YourTable EXCLUSIVE
DELETE TAG ALL

However, if you have just used the table exclusive and zapped it (pack is thus implied), the indexes will automatically be updated and still retain the .cdx file.  By doing the DELETE TAG ALL actually removes reference to the .cdx file completely.